# Passing local variable to a refenced method

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a function that passes a variable from my window.onload function to a reference of another function. I want the var i in my window.onload to be used as the actual parameter for i in the function definition of markTheSquare. edit *Sorry, I forgot to add this in the OP but the specifications specifically say that markTheSquare does not have any formal parameters*.

```
var boardState;
var markCount;// Global variable that stores the value of the number of marks.
var winningCombinations;


window.onload = function()
{
        var i;

        i = 0;
        markCount = setMarkCount(0); // calls the mutator function setMarkCount to change the value of markCount to 0.
        winningCombinations = "012345678036147258246048";
        boardState = "012345678036147258246048";

        while ( i < 9)
        {
            document.getElementById("box" + i).onclick = markTheSquare;
            i = i + 1;
        }
}
function markTheSquare() // uses the this keyword to concatenate "X" to the inner HTML of the current element.
{
    this.onclick = null; // Disassociates the oncliick function with clicked()
    this.innerHTML = getXorO(); // Concatenates the result of getXorO to the current innherHTML of the element.
    updateBoardState(getXorO(), i);
    window.alert(updateBoardState(getXorO(), i));
    setMarkCount(getMarkCount() + 1) // Increment markCount by 1.


}
function updateBoardState(getXorO, squareNumber)
{

    var boardState;
    var loc;
    var winners;

    winners = getWinningCombinations();
    boardState = getBoardState()
    loc = winners.indexOf(squareNumber);
    squareNumber = "" + squareNumber;

    while(loc >= 0)
    {
        replaceCharacterInString(boardState, loc, getXorO);
        loc = winners.indexOf(squareNumber);
    }
    return setBoardState(boardState);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add this in the OP but the specifications specifically say that markTheSquare does not have any formal parameters.

Comment: I'd have to say the specifications are wrong-headed then.  No specification should require you to pass data using shared state, but if you absolutely need to, you could use a global/shared variable or obtain `i` by parsing the element's ID.  Neither of which is better than using a parameter.

Comment: can you change the location of `markTheSquare` method definition

Comment: something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/woh0v2xL/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny No we cannot.

Comment: This is quickly turning into a riddle, instead of a productive SO question.  Arbitrary requirements that force you into writing bad code do not seem like a good fit for this site.

Comment: Can you change the contents of the function `markTheSquare`?

Answer (score 0):

You should make `markTheSquare` a factory that generates a closure.  Something like this:

```
function markTheSquare(i) {
    return function() {
       //...
       updateBoardState(getXorO(), i);
       //...
    }
}
```

The the assignment to your clickhandler is:

```
document.getElementById("box" + i).onclick = markTheSquare(i);
```

Comment: @user2009653; If you're going to add requirements to your question, you'd best list them all.  What is/is not allowed, and why not?  What do you have control over?

Comment: We can't create any more global variables and markTheSquare can have no parameters and cannot return a value. That's it.

Comment: @user2009653: Then parse `i` out of the element's ID.  It's stupid, but if that's the dumb hoop your instructor wants you to jump through, I guess you're stuck.

Comment: Can you please give me an examples? I was thinking of using this.id and doing it with that somehow.